# Units of $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Looking for the units of $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ my book says that they are $1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14$ but the only ones I agree with are $2,4,8$ because $2*8=16=1$ and also $4*4=16=1$. I just don't get how to easily identify the units do I have to trail and error each member of $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ and see which ones give me $1$?

Comment: Hint: what is $(14*8)/16$? What does this result mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a\in\Bbb Z_n$ is a unit if and only if $\gcd(a,n)=1$. So when $n=15$, you try all numbers $a\in\{0,1,2,...,13,14\}$, and see which ones are relatively prime to $15$. Since $15$ is a small integer, you can easily verify that $1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14$ are all relatively prime to $15$. However, $0,3,5,6,9,10,12$ are not relatively prime to $15$. This is because $\gcd(3,15)=\gcd(6,15)=\gcd(9,15)=\gcd(12,15)=3$, and $\gcd(5,15)=\gcd(10,15)=5$, and $\gcd(0,15)=15$.

Comment: So if it was $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ I would just need to find the relatively prime integers to 10 and those would be the units?

Comment: @pkid58 yep. This is why when $n$ is prime, $\Bbb Z_n$ is a field. Since every integer smaller than a prime is relatively prime to that prime, so every element of $\Bbb Z_n$ for $n$ prime is a unit.

Answer (score 1):

Surely $1$ is a unit. The last ones that you object to are: $7, 11, 13, 14$.

But $7 \times 13 = 91 = 15(6) + 1$, which settles matters for $7$ and $13$.

Similarly, $11^2 = 121 = 15(8) + 1$ and $14^2 = 196 = 13(15) + 1$, which settles $11$ and $14$.

Among the possible shortcuts, one is to observe that $11 = -4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$. Since $(-4)^2 = 4^2 = 1$ as you already found, this suggests squaring $11$ to get the desired result. Similarly, $14 = -1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$, and the same computation of $(-1)^2 = 1^2 = 1$ suggests squaring $14$, as well.

---

**Edit.** To build slightly on **Dave**'s answer, note that [**Bézout's identity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) states that:

> If $\gcd(a,b) = d$ then there are $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ for which $ax + by = d$.

Applied in the case of $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$, fix $b= 15$.

If $\gcd(a, 15) = 1$, then we can find $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ for which $ax + 15y = 1$; in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$, this means $ax = 1$, i.e., that $a$ is a unit.

So, as pointed out earlier, the units in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ are precisely the elements that share no divisors with $15$. (And the case for $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is entirely similar: unit iff no divisors shared with $n$.)